# How to loop through Flutter ListView tiles generated from an ObjectBox database?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-listview, flutter-objectbox

I have a Flutter app which uses ObjectBox to store back-end data, which is a list of `Product` objects. I have created a ListView Tile widget to present the data called `ProductTile`. I generate a ListView widget with the following code:

```
class productTileListView extends StatefulWidget {
  const productTileListView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<productTileListView> createState() => _productTileListViewState();
}

class _productTileListViewState extends State<productTileListView> {

  ProductTile Function(BuildContext, int) _itemBuilder(List<Product> products) {
    return (BuildContext context, int index) => ProductTile(product: products[index], setStateCallback: () => { setState(() {}) });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<List<Product>>(
      stream: objectbox.getProducts(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.data?.isNotEmpty ?? false) {
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.hasData ? snapshot.data!.length : 0,
              itemBuilder: _itemBuilder(snapshot.data ?? []));
        } else {
          return const Center(child: Text("No products"));
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

This code works perfectly, and gives me a ListView of `ProductTiles` which visualizes the data in each `Product` object. However, I am at a loss for how to loop through the `ProductTiles` to perform actions on them. For example, they track whether they are currently selected with a bool, and I would like to be able to implement something like this:
`productTiles.removeWhere((item) => item.isSelected);`
I can't perform this on the base `Product` object because `isSelected` is only part of `ProductTiles`.

One solution I have thought of is to instead change my ObjectBox database to instead store `ProductTiles`, however this seems sub-optimal as I would be storing a bunch of UI related parameters such as whether the tile is selected etc instead of storing just the necessary information.

This seems like it would be a pretty common part of app development, so please let me know what the best practice is to address this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `list` or `map` for storing selected products and pass it to your remove method.

- List elements can be either `productId` or `index`
- you can also use a map with

  - Key  : `productId` or `index`
  - Value: bool (default set to false)

Similar/Related question: [Select and deselect List Tile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74468657/select-and-deselect-list-tile)